# Debugging in Eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am debugging this code in Eclipse the code below.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))

        self.Show()
        bar = 'tt'
        car = 'aa'
        self.ss = 5 
        bttn = wx.Button(self, -1, pos=(30,10), size=(120,30))
        bttn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pr)
```

But the problem is its not showing the self.ss global inside. its only showing car and bar. Anybody any suggestion please. Badly stuck in this problem. Thank you